# Can AppleScript detect if a text entry field is active/focused within an active application?

Tags: windows, macos, macros, autohotkey, applescript

I have a number of shortcuts that I am using via QuicKeys and AppleScript to perform various functions in a focused application. Certain shortcuts, such as individual alphanumeric keys and the spacebar, should be disabled and function for text entry when a text input field is focused.

I've figured out how to disable shortcut functionality when certain application windows are focused (by name matching). But is there any way via AppleScript to detect when the active focus is a text input field?

If so, this would ***greatly*** simplify my script, since the list of windows that have one or more text input fields that I could ***potentially*** click in is getting unwieldy to keep track of and manage.

**BONUS POINTS:** This is actually a cross-platform issue. On Mac, I'm solving it using QuicKeys macros with AppleScript, and on PC I'm using AutoHotkey and Pulover's Macro Creator. So if anyone also knows how to detect if a text input field is active/focused using either AHK or PMC as well, please let me know and claim the title of *Cross-Platform Macro-Functionality Wizard*! :)

Answer (score 1):

AppleScript can detect that a text-field is focused.
I base my answer on the post
[Can I check if I am in a text field?](https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/can-i-check-if-i-am-in-a-text-field/7251)

This post contains an image from the Script Debugger of the properties of a focused
text-field, where I have outlined the properties you can use:

[image]

The text-field is identifiable by its `role` being `AXTextField`,
and the `focused` value of `true` shows that it has the focus.

I can't help with creating a precise AppleScript, since I'm not on a Mac.
But the same post also contains a script for Outlook that maybe you can use
as a model for Lightroom:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook" to activate

tell application "System Events"
  
  tell application process "Microsoft Outlook"
    set frontmost to true
    
    tell (first window whose subrole is "AXStandardWindow")
        
      set subjElem to (first text field of splitter group 1 whose description is "Subject:")
      set subjProp to properties of subjElem
      set subjFocused to focused of subjElem
            
    end tell
  end tell
end tell

return subjFocused
```

Another useful post is
[AppleScript – How can I *get* UI elements' names, attributes, properties, classes programmatically without “guessing” via AccessibilityInspector?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340942/applescript-how-can-i-get-ui-elements-names-attributes-properties-classe/)

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful info. But unfortunately I'm really weighted down and struggling through something else right now, so I'm looking for an actual "here, use this specific applescript to test and return "true" when you have a cursor active in a text field" answer in order to award the bounty. No time/energy/mental capacity to read through other threads, or write the script myself based on some other info and trial and error. Oh and in case it helps/makes a difference, the application I'm using is Reaper (the DAW).

Comment: Unfortunately, our site doesn't offer free developers. We always expect some effort from the poster.

Comment: I guess I should post scripts and screenshots of my work showing all the stuff I've tried so far to do this unsuccessfully then?

Comment: That being said, if there is a site where I can hire a programmer for the odd small job of writing a script for a few minutes or hours here or there, I wish I would've discovered it years ago, but would still be quite happy to know about it presently.

Comment: Google for "hire programmer" to find sites, but I can't help with choosing.